# Django not finding nested tests

Tags: django, django-testing

I have the following file structure:

```
project -
   - resources
       -__init__.py
       - core
          __init__.py
          tests.py
```

My test code looks like this:

```
class TestEmailHelper(TestCase):

def test_send_mail(self):
    EmailHelper.send_email(EmailHelper.SLUGS.ORDER_COMPLETED, 'lee@lee.com', {})
    assert len(mail.outbox) == 1, "Inbox is not empty"
```

Here is the config in the app apps.py file:

```
class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'resources.core'
```

And, of course, this is in my INSTALLED_APPS and works perfectly fine except for finding the tests.

if I attempt to run all tests, I get the response 'No Tests ran, please check the configuration settings fo the tests.

if I use this command, it works:

```
python3 manage.py test resources/core
```

If I use this command, I get a module not found error looking for 'core':

```
python3 manage.py test core
```

It seems to me it may have something to do with having my app nested due to the error caused when I dont append the pat with 'resources'. But I'm not sure how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

In python indentation is important, you have to indent your `def` declaration under your `class`:

```
class TestEmailHelper(TestCase):

    def test_send_mail(self):
        EmailHelper.send_email(EmailHelper.SLUGS.ORDER_COMPLETED, 'lee@lee.com', {})
        assert len(mail.outbox) == 1, "Inbox is not empty"
```

Comment: Sorry, but it seems this comment is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
All my apps are in the 'apps' directory nested into the project main directory, with settings, WSGI, and .ect.
So the conclusion I came to is to use a command like this(to execute all my nested apps tests):

```
    python manage.py test project/apps
```

, or create a custom test command which is inherited from the build-in 'test' command and override its 'handle' method transferring the path to my apps directory.

```
    from django.core.management.commands import test


    class Command(test.Command):

        def handle(self, *args, **options):
            test_labels = 'project/apps'
            super().handle(test_labels, **options)
```

The docs on how to create commands in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/